# How to add keyboard shortcut for "Move to Predicted Mailbox" in Apple Mail?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, shortcut

In Apple Mail (under macOS Catalina, 10.15.3) there is a menu item "Move to Predicted Mailbox" .
It already has a keyboard shortcut ^ CMD M.

I would like to change that to something else.
Now, the problem is that this menu item changes every time I select a different message, depending on the folder Mail predicts. So, one time it is called 'Move to "MailboxA"'  , another time it might be called 'Move to "MailboxB"' .
Consequently, I cannot define a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences for it. I have tried to define it for "Move to Predicted Mailbox", but when Mail actually does predict a mailbox, then it shows the original shortcut, not mine.

Does anyone have an idea how I might be able to define a shortcut for this that "sticks"?

Comment: Can confirm. I also tried out "Move to…" (with and without ellipsis) as this shows up when you add the button with the "move to predicted mailbox"-behaviour to the toolbar, and Mail does not have a prediction. To no avail.

And for reference: When I am using "Move to Predicted Mailbox" my shortcut actually does appear in the menu when I am on a mail without a predicted destination mailbox - but then it is grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

There are built in shortcuts for the Favorites bar – the bar shown here that has "Mailboxes Inbox (5) 2021Q1 2020Q4 (1)".

[image]

The shortcuts are <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<number>, where *number* is the position on the bar with "inbox" getting position 1. So to move to 2021Q1 on my favorites bar, I hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+2 (probably my most hit keyboard shortcut since my current archive folder also holds this spot on my favorites bar).

If you don't see the favorites bar, show it from the View menu, "Show Favorites Bar." Then drag your preferred folders from the folder list on the left onto the favorites bar.